# Which civil airport has the longest runways in total?

Tags: airport

It's quite easy to google information about which civil airport has the longest runways, but what I'm really looking for (and having a hard time to find) is which airport has the longest runways in total - I mean if you add up all the lengths, disregarding the direction - which one be the winner?

Comment: Makes sense, let me edit the question to make is specifically about civil airport.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all of Rogers Lake is at least somewhat suitable for use as a runway :P

Comment: Perhaps the Black Rock City Munincipal airport (88NV: http://www.airnav.com/airport/88nv ).  Though it's officially only 7000 ft, it has upwards of 40 miles of unpaved landing area available if needed.  And room for quite a number of parallel runways, too :-)

Comment: To add to Unrecognized's comment, if you add up all the paved *and* **dry lake bed** runways at [EDW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwards_Air_Force_Base#Airfield), well that's 213,244 feet.

Comment: Related: [Which civilian airport has the most runways (current and planned)?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33425/1696)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Best I can find, within the US, is KDFW with 80,403' of total length. Second seems to be KDEN with 76,000'. Glanced at KORD, and with mental math it comes up to about 71,000'. Most other major airports are well behind all of these, mainly because they don't have as ***many*** long runways as DFW and DEN.

Somebody else can consider Russian, Chinese, and Middle Eastern airports -- I don't have the chart sets handy for those.  May be worth converting this to a community wiki answer if any of those places give interesting results.

Comment: I thought of EHAM, but it's only got 63,800.

Answer (score 6):

Based on my current navigation database (AIRAC 1911), the following 20 airports have the longest total runway length:

- [KDFW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dallas/Fort_Worth_International_Airport): 7 runways with a total length of 80,403 ft (longest 13,401 ft)
- [KDEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denver_International_Airport): 6 runways with a total length of 76,000 ft (longest 16,000 ft)
- [EHAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amsterdam_Airport_Schiphol): 6 runways with a total length of 63,688 ft (longest 12,467 ft)
- [KORD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%27Hare_International_Airport): 7 runways with a total length of 62,342 ft (longest 13,000 ft)
- [KDTW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detroit_Metropolitan_Airport): 6 runways with a total length of 57,713 ft (longest 12,003 ft)
- <strike>[KEDW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwards_Air_Force_Base): 4 runways with a total length of 56,143 ft (longest 21,119 ft)</strike> (not civilian)
- [LTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Istanbul_Airport): 4 runways with a total length of 51,508 ft (longest 13,451 ft)
- [KIAH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Bush_Intercontinental_Airport): 5 runways with a total length of 50,403 ft (longest 12,001 ft)
- [CYYZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toronto_Pearson_International_Airport): 5 runways with a total length of 49,955 ft (longest 11,120 ft)
- [LEMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolfo_Su%C3%A1rez_Madrid%E2%80%93Barajas_Airport): 4 runways with a total length of 49,761 ft (longest 13,711 ft)
- [KATL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartsfield%E2%80%93Jackson_Atlanta_International_Airport): 5 runways with a total length of 49,389 ft (longest 12,390 ft)
- [ZSPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanghai_Pudong_International_Airport): 4 runways with a total length of 49,212 ft (longest 13,123 ft)
- [ZBAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beijing_Daxing_International_Airport): 4 runways with a total length of 48,556 ft (longest 12,467 ft)
- [LIRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo_da_Vinci%E2%80%93Fiumicino_Airport): 4 runways with a total length of 48,272 ft (longest 12,802 ft)
- [PHNL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_K._Inouye_International_Airport): 6 runways with a total length of 48,264 ft (longest 12,312 ft)
- [LFPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_de_Gaulle_Airport): 4 runways with a total length of 45,085 ft (longest 13,780 ft)
- [KJFK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_F._Kennedy_International_Airport): 4 runways with a total length of 44,990 ft (longest 14,511 ft)
- [KLAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles_International_Airport): 4 runways with a total length of 43,829 ft (longest 12,923 ft)
- [KLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McCarran_International_Airport): 4 runways with a total length of 43,800 ft (longest 14,515 ft)
- [KMCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orlando_International_Airport): 4 runways with a total length of 43,010 ft (longest 12,005 ft)

As Ralph J said in [his answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/43208/which-civil-airport-has-the-longest-runways-in-total/43211#43211), **Dallas/Fort Worth (KDFW)** comes first (also worldwide) due to the large number of runways (also highest worldwide, together with KORD). In Europe, the winner is **Amsterdam Schiphol (EHAM)** and in Asia, the winner is **Shanghai Pudong (ZSPD)**.

In total 11 out of the 19 civilian airports listed above are in the United States.

The highest average runway length of the 19 civilian airports listed above has **Istanbul Airport (LTFM)** at 12,877 ft.

[image: Total Runway Length Comparison]

Answer (score 0):

Qamdo Bamda Airport (ZUBD) has one runway that measures 18,045ft.(5,500M) long

Comment: The question is asking for the highest *total* runway length, i.e. if you add all runways together